# C++11 compile time type check

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr

I'm working on compile-time type check in C++11. For this toy code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr bool IsMyType(std::vector<T>&) // case 1: code works as expected
// constexpr bool IsMyType(std::vector<T>) // case 2: error
{
    return std::is_same<T, int>::value || std::is_same<T, float>::value;
}

std::vector<double> x;
constexpr bool result = IsMyType(x);
static_assert(result, "--> incompatible type!!");
```

When the parameter is not passed by reference, g++ (v4.9.4) reports:

> error: ‘constexpr bool IsMyType(std::vector) [with T = double]’
>   called in a constant expression
>        constexpr bool result = IsMyType(x);
>
> note: ‘constexpr bool IsMyType(std::vector) [with T = double]’ is
>   not usable as a constexpr function because:  constexpr bool
>   IsMyType(std::vector)

May I know the reason for the error and note, and why pass-by-reference makes the compile-time execution possible?

Comment: Passing by value requires running the vector's copy constructor, which naturally is not `constexpr`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks. May I know if it is true that copy of non-constexpr built-in variables in general is also not constexpr? If I have another overloaded template IsMyType(T), for non-constexpr built-in types such as "float y = 100.0f", the error becomes: "error: the value of ‘y’ is not usable in a constant expression".

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are saying. [This works for me](http://rextester.com/LCJQ74292)